# Matrix problem Python

Tags: python, sum

For example if I have matrix:

```
x=[['1', '7', 'U1'], ['1.5', '8', 'U1'], ['2', '5.5', 'U2']]
```

How can I take all data from x, except the last one. Then I need to sum this elements.

---

This is what I need: `sum=1+7+1.5+8+2+5.5= ??`

Thanks

---

---

### EDIT2:

---

I try:

```
> x=[['1', '7', 'U1'], ['1.5', '8',
> 'U1'], ['2', '5.5', 'U2']]
> 
> sum(sum(el[:-1]) for el in x)
```

But received error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "xxx.py", line 3, in 
>       sum(sum(el[:-1]) for el in x)   File "xxx.py", line 3, in 
>       sum(sum(el[:-1]) for el in x) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)
>   for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can take all elements apart from the last one indexing with `[:-1]`.

To take that sum, try `sum(sum(float(el) for el in els[:-1]) for els in x)`.

If you actually have strings in the list, you might need to cast the elements. Also, if there are always 3 elements, this could be a bit faster:

```
sum(float(a) + float(b) for a,b,_ in x)
```

Comment: Hmm, I received error, please look at EDIT 2; 
There is not always 3 elements it's random data, so random "inputs"...

Comment: First example didnt' use casting. I updated it to change the values into floats.

Comment: Maybe you know how can i get length of this array. I know that it's something in this way len(x); but this is for array. It must count all elements except the last one of x "matrix". So in my case result must be 6.
thanks