# Python Matrix length

Tags: python, matrix

How can I get length of random Matrix(except last element in every row), for example:

```
x=[['1', '7', 'U1'], ['1.5', '8', 'U1'], ['2', '5.5', 'U2']]
```

I know that for length Python use "`len(x)`", but it's not correct

**Result must be in this case 6 (last element on every row not count)**

thanks

Comment: Did you read the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781294/matrix-problem-python?  It shows how to skip the last element in each row.  What was wrong with that answer?

Comment: this is not a Matrix, it is a list of lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum(len(xx) - 1 for xx in x)` should work.

Comment: @thaking: Since this is not the same as the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781294/matrix-problem-python, I expect hilarity to ensue with yet another question trying to reconcile the two answers.